# Converting Shell Curl command to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am using an [API](https://github.com/mimblewimble/docs/wiki/Wallet-JSON-RPC-API-Guide) I found online for querying a remote Grin daemon using curl. I am trying to convert the bash curl request below into PHP, but I am not sure how I pass the `.api_secret` using PHP's curl library.

**Bash**

`` $ curl -0 -XPOST -u grin:`cat ~/.grin/floo/.api_secret` --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"retrieve_summary_info","params":[true, 10],"id":1}' http://127.0.0.1:13420/v2/owner ``

The main part of this command I am confused about is as follows:

`` grin:`cat ~/.grin/floo/.api_secret` ``

How do I convert the command above into PHP format? **This is what I have so far**:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:13420/v2/owner');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"retrieve_summary_info\",\"params\":[true, 10],\"id\":1}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
return $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: use `file_get_contents` in it's place - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer @treyBake but could you please elaborate a little, I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As treyBake says, you can get it by using `file_get_contents` and sending it to cURL with the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option. Like so:

```
// your path needs to either be relative or full, no '~' allowed
// example: '/home/grin/.grin/floo/.api_secret'
$secret = file_get_contents(PATH);
if (!$secret)
    return;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "grin:$secret");
```

Comment: Perfect, that makes a lot of sense